# Foreign Key Column not Recognized

Tags: sqlite, lazarus

I have 4 tables: Attendees, History, Attendee_Owes, and Balance. Tables History and Attendee_Owes have FKs referencing Attendees PK.

History holds all payment history for the Attendees.

Attendee_Owes holds the last record only for each attendee from History table.

The schemas for these two tables are:

```
sqlite> .schema history
CREATE TABLE HISTORY(
HISTORY_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
LAST_PAYMENT_DATE VARCHAR NOT NULL,
CURRENT_PAYMENT_DATE VARCHAR NOT NULL,
SUBSIDY VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
WEEKLY_PAYMENT REAL NOT NULL,
AMOUNT_PAID REAL NOT NULL,
HISTORY_BALANCE REAL NOT NULL,
HIST_ATTENDEE_ID INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY(HIST_ATTENDEE_ID) REFERENCES ATTENDEES(ATTENDEE_ID) 
ON DELETE CASCADE 
ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

sqlite> .schema attendee_owes
CREATE TABLE ATTENDEE_OWES(
OWES_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
ATTENDEE_OWES_BALANCE REAL NOT NULL,
OWES_ATTENDEE_ID INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY(OWES_ATTENDEE_ID) REFERENCES ATTENDEES(ATTENDEE_ID)
ON DELETE CASCADE 
ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

My problem is a trigger that fires when a history record is deleted.

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_history_delete
AFTER DELETE ON history
BEGIN
   UPDATE ATTENDEE_OWES SET ATTENDEE_OWES_BALANCE = (SELECT HISTORY_BALANCE FROM HISTORY ORDER BY HISTORY_ID DESC LIMIT 1) WHERE OWES_ATTENDEE_ID = HIST_ATTENDEE_ID;
END;
```

I get an error at the end of the UPDATE statement: No such column: HIST_Attendee_ID

I've tried:

```
UPDATE ATTENDEE_OWES SET ATTENDEE_OWES_BALANCE = (SELECT HISTORY_BALANCE FROM HISTORY ORDER BY HISTORY_ID DESC LIMIT 1) WHERE OWES_ATTENDEE_ID = HISTORY.HIST_ATTENDEE_ID;
```

and

```
UPDATE ATTENDEE_OWES SET ATTENDEE_OWES_BALANCE = (SELECT HISTORY_BALANCE FROM HISTORY ORDER BY HISTORY_ID DESC LIMIT 1) WHERE OWES_ATTENDEE_ID = HISTORY(HIST_ATTENDEE_ID);
```

but I still get an error there telling me no such column.

I've tried all I know. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Lets look to your SQL in the more convenient way:

```
UPDATE ATTENDEE_OWES SET 
  ATTENDEE_OWES_BALANCE = (
    SELECT HISTORY_BALANCE 
    FROM HISTORY 
    ORDER BY HISTORY_ID DESC LIMIT 1) 
WHERE 
  OWES_ATTENDEE_ID = HIST_ATTENDEE_ID;
```

As we can see OWES_ATTENDEE_ID = HIST_ATTENDEE_ID is related to the topmost level where table HISTORY is not known.
Right query must be:

```
UPDATE ATTENDEE_OWES SET 
  ATTENDEE_OWES_BALANCE = (
    SELECT HISTORY_BALANCE 
    FROM HISTORY
    WHERE OWES_ATTENDEE_ID = HIST_ATTENDEE_ID
    ORDER BY HISTORY_ID DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Indeed, it's the correct query. Worked like a charm. Thanks Abelisto.